# How to test if Modal (react-native) is visible or not using Jest?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-native-testing-library

Modal also does not have a testID prop.

Also, I'm using Modal from 'react-native' and not 'react-native-modal'

Comment: Using `expect(UNSAFE_getAllByType(Modal)[1].props.visible).toBe(true);` for now. It's a bad hack, but it works.

Comment: what is the library you are using, enzyme or 
react-native-testing-library? please add a tag.

Comment: @RoniCastro react-native-testing-library